# Cannot access "System.Servicemodel.Web" in Portable Class library even though visible in Object Browser

Tags: c#, portability, portable-class-library

All the docs I've read to date suggest you can do web service libraries from a Portable Class Library, they all state that:

- System.ServiceModel &
- System.ServiceModel.Web

Are available for use fro things like "WebGet" attributes and other WCF Rest features.

However When I try and reference the namespace it says it's not available and browsing in code does not show the namespace.

I would normally take this to mean it's not available in a portable class library but the namespace is visible in the Object Browser.

I've even tried limiting the frameworks I'm targeting to just:

- .NET 4.03 and Above
- Silverlight 4 and above

But no Joy.  Even just using SL5 and .NET 4.5 still doesn't expose the namespace

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer quite simply is NO

You can all all the basic [DataContract] / [ServiceOperation] / [DataMember] attributes in a PCL project but you cannot put Rest Implementation attributes on anything.

The simple answer to to provide as much as you can for attributes in the PCL and then apply the Rest attributes in your concrete implementation (does need to live in the PCL)

Also of note, a lot of the serialisable tags are lost when you use a PCL, so be use to add [DataContract] [DataMember] attributes to all of your models and properties else you will have issues I have found.

Comment: [Microsoft's How To Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412196.aspx) says to add a `[WebGet]` attribute, and that is located in [System.ServiceModel.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx) - but VS2010 does not let me add that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some kind of flaw in Visual Studio 2010 with respect to this. Even though the `System.ServiceModel` and `System.ServiceModel.Web` assemblies appear to be automatically referenced, they *are not* by default, and the corresponding namespaces are not available:

[image: ServiceModel namespace not defined]

To workaround this issue, open the *Add references* dialog. All assemblies will appear to be referenced, but neither of them are included in the project *References* list:

[image: Assemblies appear to be referenced]

To **really** add a desired assembly to your project, select the assembly from the list. Now, first click *Remove* and then immediately click *Add* (alternatively, double-click the assembly twice in the list). After doing this, the "removed/added" assembly will now explicitly appear in the project's *References* list:

[image: Removing/adding assemblies]

The corresponding namespaces and classes are now available as you type:

[image: ServiceModel namespace available]

and the project can be successfully built.

This appears to work even for the broadest platform inclusion, i.e. .NET Framework 4+, Silverlight 4+, WP7+ and Windows Store apps. This has been tested on VS 2010 with the latest PCL add-in.

On Visual Studio 2012, the *.NET Portable Subset* is listed as a monolith and it is not possible to (de-) reference individual assemblies of the subset. However, on VS 2012 access to the `System.ServiceModel` etc. assemblies seem to be automatically covered when you create a new Portable Class Library.

All the above has been tested on a Windows 7 system with non-Express Visual Studio versions.

Comment: That seems reasonable, however in VS2010 this causes VS to crash and doesn't save the reference change.  in VS2012 it's not available and adding it manually states it's already referenced :S

Comment: Odd? A temporary fault, maybe? Have you installed the latest Visual Studio updates, including the latest Portable Library Tools add-in? I do not experience any crashes, and when I close and re-open VS2010 the references are maintained. As updated, on VS2012 it seems like you automatically get access to the `System.ServiceModel` namespaces.

Comment: Found the cause, the "Productivity Tools" advanced reference dialog got broken when re-applying SP1.  Removed it and can add references fine.  However upon investigating further, when looking at "System.ServiceModel.Web" in Object browser, only the JSON namespace is available.

Comment: Yes, if you for example look at the MSDN documentation for the [System.ServiceModel.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.aspx) namespace none of the classes are marked as being available in PCL. If you require a larger part of the *System.ServiceModel.Web* assembly, you will most probably have to create a .NET Framework dedicated project.

Comment: [Microsoft's How To Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412196.aspx) says to add a `[WebGet]` attribute, and that is located in [System.ServiceModel.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx) - but VS2010 does not let me add that file. Is that the same issue we are running into here?